# Is there a dynamic-creation-friendly LinkLabel Alternative?

Tags: c#, winforms, linklabel

I'm trying to dynamically create a link from a Windows Form to our website when certain conditions are met (it's a warning message with further information in our online manual).

Currently I'm finding [LinkLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx) quite unwieldy to use in this situation: having to set up LinkClicked handlers on the fly for a straightforward hyperlink seems inelegant.

Is there a wrapper or alternative that fulfills the following requirements?:

- Inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Control (so I can use it in a TableLayoutPanel)
- Has reasonably low setup (no strange LinkClicked function pre-visit checking, for example)
- Isn't bound to a specific browser

Comment: Do you mean 3rd party component?

Comment: @polishchuk: If at all avoidable, preferably not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used [`LinkLabel.Links.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkcollection.add%28v=vs.85%29) to modify the link destination dynamically..

Answer (score 2):

What is your problem with the `LinkClicked` event handler? You would have to do the same for almost any control in order to do anything useful.

Anyway, it would be trivial to implement yourself - create a class that inherits from LinkLabel, add a string `URL` property (you may need an attribute to make this show in the designer properties panel if you want to set it that way) and provide an event handler that opens the browser with that URL.

Then you can just add the control in the designer (or at runtime), set the URL property and it will work without having to set event handlers.

Comment: I was indeed considering writing a control that inherits from LinkLabel, but I was hoping there was an alternative (or an existing code sample) to save me the trouble. Inevitably I would have coded such only to discover there was an alternative class all along.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't anything unless you want a 3rd party component (which your previous comments rule out). I can see why you think the LinkLabel is unwieldy - you could always set the event handler with an anonymous function (nice example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359629/is-there-anything-wrong-with-using-lambda-for-winforms-event), which looks a bit cleaner and lets you set the URL on-the-fly when the control is created/event handler set.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the `LinkClicked` event instead of `OnClick`? Then you can use this in the event handler:

```
    (sender as LinkLabel).LinkVisited = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://example.com");
```

It's not bound a specific browser - opens in the user's default browser. The setup is low - just instantiate the LinkLabel, add an event hookup to `LinkClicked` (which is one two-line method) and add it to the page. What's unwieldy about this approach?

Comment: Ah, I think that's too much time with JavaScript lately I my part: LinkClicked is the name of the event I was thinking of (editing now).

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure what your hesitation is with this - could you explain more fully?

Comment: It's the need to create the label mid-code in possibly more than one instance (with different links) that makes creating those event handlers awkward.